# bootstrap 5.3 dashboard is not working properly

Tags: bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 5.3.0 dashboard template is not working properly (sidebar is hidden) when page size is between 768px and 991px. How to rectify this error please?

link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/dashboard/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AL1i.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPKE6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
<div class="offcanvas-lg offcanvas-end bg-body-tertiary" tabindex="-1" id="sidebarMenu" aria-labelledby="sidebarMenuLabel">
```

change `offcanvas-lg` to `offcanvas-md` and it should show up properly.